# @Html.AntiForgeryToken() invalidating previous tokens

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my Asp.Net Core website, I use @Html.AntiForgeryToken() to generate a token for my client side code and I protect my Controllers with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute.  This works great with one exception.  Every time I open a new page,  @Html.AntiForgeryToken() is called again, which generates a token unique to the page.  This new token works for the current page, but if I had another tab open, that tab ceases to work, because it is still using the old token.  Each time I open a new tab, all previous tabs stop working with the generation of the new token by @Html.AntiForgeryToken().

This seems like the wrong behavior.  Just because I open another tab, my existing tabs should continue to work for the lifetime of the session.

I confirmed that this behavior is different in Asp.Net Framework.  Similarly, each call to @Html.AntiForgeryToken() generates a new token, but when I pass the token to System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, headerValue), all previously generated tokens continue to work, as opposed to only the most recent token working.

How can I get existing tokens to continue to work for the lifetime of the session when new tokens are generated with @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in Asp.Net Core?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0#multiple-browser-tabs-and-the-synchronizer-token-pattern This doc mentioned it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @quingfu for pointing out the official MS documentation stating that the Synchronizer Token Pattern does not support multiple open tabs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0#multiple-browser-tabs-and-the-synchronizer-token-pattern

To work around this I introduced a cookie to my website that I set in each view load in a script in _Layout.cshtml with the antiforgery token.  Then, instead of grabbing the token out of the Html.AntiForgeryToken hidden field, I grab it from the cookie.  Each new view load resets the cookie to a new value, but since the cookie is shared across all tabs, the old browser tabs continue to work after new ones are loaded.